# Run magit-log with predefined arguments

Tags: emacs, magit

How can I set some predefined arguments to magit-log and run it using some key binding? Say for example I want to quickly open magit-log with arguments "-n150" "--simplify-decoration" "--full-history" on all branches without doing this via the popup that is normally started with magit-log.

I can use transient to save the arguments and later use them, but the magit-popup still needs to be shown first, involving too many key bindings for this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Digging through magit-log it looks like your request can be done by calling with magit version 2.90....

```
(magit-log-all-branches '("-n150" "--simplify-by-decoration" "--full-history"))
```